# How can I close a chat or freeze it?

Tags: support, chat

In the Help Center I find a lot of information on how to open a chat, but so far I couldn't find out what to do, when I don't need the chat any more.

Do I have to close it somehow or is just leaving the chat room the right choice and it will be closed/get frozen after some time by itself?

Comment: The room will be automatically deleted or frozen after 1 or 2 weeks, depending on how many posts and users were in it. See http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention for the full details.

Comment: You cannot act on it unless you're a moderator in at least one SE site.

Comment: @PaulGessler, many thanks for that link. I remember that I had a look at the FAQ, but I would never have guessed that I will find the answer under the topic "Will these rooms exist forever?". If you like to state your comment as answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person
>   actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if
>   it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be
>   deleted. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be
>   frozen. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are
>   not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms
>   interface.

Only moderators can take action to remove/freeze rooms; normal users cannot and must wait for an automatic action by the system as described above.